# .NET Powerpoint presentation stopping after 4 hours?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I wrote a command line application in C#.NET that programmatically edits an existing powerpoint, and then starts the slideshow. The powerpoint is automatically configured to advance slides. The problem I am running into is that powerpoint will quit after 4 hours. Any ideas?

Comment: the computer went to sleep

Comment: +1 I vote for a sleeping computer also!

Answer (score 2):

I think the computer is going to sleep or my other guess is that the program is causing a memory leak causing the program to crash out and close.

Comment: It is not the computer going to sleep, I have added in mouse movements to keep the computer from locking up.

Comment: It still sounds like it could be a memory leak to me.Make sure your program is running for like an hour. Go to your task manager then to the processes click the memory header until it sorts them descending. Now see if that program is the top of the list for memory usage if so that means it is a mem leak and you need some more garbage collection in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer's gone to sleep or the screensaver has kicked in, waking it back up should put you back inside a running slide show.

If the slide show has actually stopped, I think you can rule out a sleeping computer/screensaver problem.  In that case, it might be a problem with your program or it might be that PPT just craps out after some amount of time running a slide show.  In some versions on some computers (nobody's ever been able to pin down the magic combo that triggers this).

To rule that out, start the presentation independent of your app and see if it runs w/o problems.

Comment: It is not the computer going to sleep, I have added in mouse movements to keep the computer from locking up. I just opened the presentation and started the slideshow separately from my application to see if it quits after 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Like everybody already mentioned. Maybe the screensaver or when the Presentation is over, it closes. Maybe you could write your program in such way, that when it is on the last slide, to start again from the 1st one, which will actually create an infinite loop. If your goal is to only show the slide show.